# Libgdx & Android: Playing multiple sounds fast causes game to freeze/stutter

Tags: android, performance, audio, libgdx

I'm using mp3 files to play sounds in my Android game, developed in Libgdx. The sounds play fine when they happen every now and then, but when I play them fast (footsteps in a running animation for example) the game freezes/stutters.

Every time a sound is played, I get this in the logs:

```
W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 4, track 44100 Hz, output 48000 Hz
```

I use libktx AssetStorage to store the sounds. I've been searching for this issue for a few days now and haven't gotten luck with any of the following solutions:

- Override createAudio in AndroidLauncher and use AsynchronousAndroidAudio
- Convert mp3 to ogg (using Audacity)
- Convert to 48k rate sample (using Audacity)
- Add 1 or seconds of silence to the file

I test it on my own device, Samsung Galaxy S5, which is quite old and has version Android 6.0.1.

What can I do to resolve this error and stuttering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding compressed audio can be a significant processing load. If it's a short recording (e.g., one footstep that is being repeated), I'd either package the sound file as a .wav or decode it into PCM to be held in memory, and use it that way. IDK if it's possible to output PCM directly with libgdx, though, but I do recall inspecting and tinkering with an ogg utility to have it decode into an array, and outputting it with a `SourceDataLine` for a non-libgdx Java project. I realize that `SourceDataLine` output is not an option with Android, but Android does have provisions for playing back raw PCM.

Another idea to explore is raising the priority of the thread that is processing the audio to `Thread.MAX_PRIORITY` if libgdx allows this. Theoretically, the audio processing thread spends most of its time in a blocked state, so doing this shouldn't hurt the performance, unless you are really going overboard with your audio requests.

I just saw the mismatch of sample rates. It's wasteful to repeatedly do conversions on the fly when you can do the conversion once in Audacity. I'm guessing the difference between outputting at 48000 vs 44100 isn't that big of a load difference. Seems to me 44100 should be fine, but I doubt using 48000 for everything adds much in terms of cpu load (or perceivable audio fidelity). So, whichever one you pick, spend a little time making sure all the assets match the format.

Comment: I'm not sure how to set thread priority but by using wav files I can already see the improvements. You're right for short files I should use wav to avoid much decoding. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool, am glad this helped! As far as setting thread priorities, the command is https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority(int) but there are a few things to consider. Mainly, IDK that the code used by libgdx for media playback blocks like `SourceDataLine`. If it uses some sort of polling strategy it could potentially dominate and slow down everything else. Also, IDK specifics of identifying the thread. With SourceDataLine, the thread is simply the same one where its write method is executed. Cheers